# Convert escaped utf-8 string to utf in python 3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a py3 string that includes escaped utf-8 sequencies, such as "Company\\ffffffc2\\ffffffae", which I would like to convert to the correct utf 8 string (which would in the example be "Company®", since the escaped sequence is c2 ae). I've tried

```
print (bytes("Company\\\\ffffffc2\\\\ffffffae".replace(
    "\\\\ffffff", "\\x"), "ascii").decode("utf-8"))
```

result: Company\xc2\xae

```
 print (bytes("Company\\\\ffffffc2\\\\ffffffae".replace (
     "\\\\ffffff", "\\x"), "ascii").decode("unicode_escape"))
```

result: CompanyÂ®

(wrong, since chracters are treated separately, but they should be treated together.

If I do

```
print (b"Company\xc2\xae".decode("utf-8"))
```

It gives the correct result. 
Company®

How can i achieve that programmatically (i.e. starting from a py3 str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
import ast

test_in = "Company\\\\ffffffc2\\\\ffffffae"
test_out = ast.literal_eval("b'''" + test_in.replace('\\\\ffffff','\\x') + "'''").decode('utf-8')
print(test_out)
```

However it will fail if there is a triple quote `'''` in the input string itself.

---

Following code does not have this problem, but it is not as simple as the first one.

In the first step the string is split on a regular expression. The odd items are ascii parts, e.g. `"Company"`; each even item corresponds to one escaped utf8 code, e.g. `"\\\\ffffffc2"`. Each substring is converted to bytes according to its meaning in the input string. Finally all parts are joined together and decoded from bytes to a string.

```
import re

REGEXP = re.compile(r'(\\\\ffffff[0-9a-f]{2})', flags=re.I)

def convert(estr):
    def split(estr):
        for i, substr in enumerate(REGEXP.split(estr)):
            if i % 2:
                yield bytes.fromhex(substr[-2:])
            elif substr:
                yield bytes(substr, 'ascii')
    return b''.join(split(estr)).decode('utf-8')


test_in = "Company\\\\ffffffc2\\\\ffffffae"
print(convert(test_in))
```

The code could be optimized. Ascii parts do not need encode/decode and consecutive hex codes should be concatenated.